# Define a nested or recursive list structure in Elm

Tags: elm

I'm trying to learn Elm using [Haskell 99 Questions](https://wiki.haskell.org/99_questions/1_to_10). In question 7 you have to define a nested list structure. I've tried this: (based somewhat on reading [this](http://elm-lang.org/guide/model-the-problem#recursive-data-structures))

```
type NestedList a = Node a | List (NestedList a)

myList : NestedList number
myList =
  [Node 1]
```

However I get this following error:

```
The type annotation is saying:
  NestedList number

But I am inferring that the definition has this type:
  List (NestedList number)
```

This doesn't make sense to me. Surely `List (NestedList number)` is matched by the second side of `Node a | List (NestedList a)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem #7 requires you to use the built-in Elm `List` type as part of your `NestedList` definition, but the way you've defined your `NestedList` type actually creates a constructor called `List` which inadvertently hides the built-in `List` type. I think this type signature is actually going to give you what you're after:

```elm
type NestedList a = Node a | NestedList (List (NestedList a))
```

Your `myList` signature should now change since it should actually return a `List` of `NestedList`s:

```elm
myList : List (NestedList number)
myList =
  [Node 1]
```

Given this new definition, you can achieve the nesting problem #7 is asking for. You can define more complex lists like this:

```elm
-- e.g. [1,2, [3, 4, [5]], 6]
myListierList : List (NestedList number)
myListierList =
  [Node 1, Node 2, NestedList [Node 3, Node 4, NestedList [Node 5]], Node 6]
```

Comment: Ok cool, so by using `List` for `NestedList` in the definition it's started using that, rather than the built-in name. So as a follow-up, how might I define a more complex structure e.g. [1,2, [3, 4, [5]], 6] using this?

Comment: I've updated my answer to more adequately capture the spirit of problem #7, and it includes your complex nested list example.

Comment: Great. I think it'll take sometime for this to sink in... So a NestedList of things is either a thing Node or a NestedList of Lists of NestedLists of things! Thanks for taking the time - much appreciated.